# How to split python list into lists of different lengths?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, zip

How to make function that can execute list comprehension(zip?) The sublists should have different lengths which are given.

Example:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
   
myNum = (2,4,3)
```

Desired outcome:

```
newList = ['(1,2)', '(3,4,5,6)', '(7,8,9)']
```

Comment: Watch out. `myList` is a list, but `myNum` is a tuple. A quick search brings an answer to your question;  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks.

Answer (score 1):

If it does not have to be a List comprehension, you can solve it like this:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
myNum = (2,4,3)
prev = 0
newList = []
for i in myNum:
    newList.append(tuple(myList[prev:prev+i]))
    prev = prev+i
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
myNum = (2,4,3) 
newList = [] 

for i in myNum:
   newList.append(tuple(myList[:i]))
   [ myList.pop(myList.index(x)) for x in myList[:i] ]
print(newList)
```

OR

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
myNum = (2,4,3) 
newList = [] 
x = 0
for i in myNum:
   if x == 0:
       newList.append(tuple(myList[:i]))
       x = myList[:i][-1] 
   else:
       end_index = myList[myList.index(x)+1 : myList.index(x)+1+i]
       newList.append(tuple(end_index))
       x = end_index[-1]
print(newList)
```